# Hibernate Envers : modified field flag name

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm currently trying to set up a project with Hibernate Envers.

I've set the property `org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag` to `true` which seems to work but the engine generates modified fields names as their related entity's field name.

**Example :**

```
@Column(name = "is_active")
private boolean active;
```

gives

```
SELECT ..., ****0_*_.is_active as is_activ*_***_*_, ****0_*_.active_MOD as active_M*_***_*_, ...
```

**Is there a possibility to keep the column name with suffix _MOD ?**

Like this : `****0_*_.is_active_MOD as is_activ*_***_*_`

**EDIT :**

Found final class `AuditMetadataGenerator#addModifiedFlagIfNeeded` in `hibernate-envers-4.3.8.Final` which inject modified flag name staidly...

It seems I'll probably have to request feature.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported as a feature, [HHH-10398](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10398).